# ldappassword for user without ldap password prompt

Tags: ldap

I installed pam,nss and ldap authentication.

I have two rule host : 183 -- installed openldap server, 123-- installed openldap client.

my ldap system works fine.

But What i want to do is:

when I login into SSH using ldap user, I want to them to change the password using ldappasswd but when I do that It asks for new password as well as LDAP Password.. I want user to change password without providing ldap password.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard good practice for any program that allows a user to change their password to prompt for the old password first, so that only someone who knows the password can change it.

This prevents their password from being changed by pranksters (e.g. if they have left themselves logged in while wandering off to get a coffee) and by crackers who have somehow managed to gain access without knowing the password.

root, or the LDAP administrator, can of course change any user's password without knowing what the original password was.